# Generate pandas Dataframe with values as comma separated

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Generating dataframe with comma separated values in pandas python

```
   arr1 = ['a','b','c']
   arr2 = ['1','2','3']
   data = { 'A': arr1, 'B': arr2 }
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   blank = [''] * len(arr1)
   df.index = blank
   return df
```

returns the output

```
A  B
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

I want the result returned like the below

```
A,B
a,1
b,2
c,3
```

Is there anyway to do this using Dataframe ?
note: Do not want to print data, need to return this as output from the function.

Comment: you want the result to be what type? still a dataframe, or a string? I understand you don't want too print, maybe tell us how you gonna use it after? or you want a 1-column daatframe with all the values of a row aggregated in a cell?

Comment: @Ben.T return type as dataframe. I want this to just return not going to use it after

Comment: Sorry but it is really confusing. Do you need to save it in csv file at least? otherwise no print and not using it later, why would you need your data to look this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single column, why do you build a DataFrame with two?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A,B': arr1})
df['A,B'] += ','
df['A,B'] += arr2
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A,B':[f'{a},{b}' for a,b in zip(arr1, arr2)]})
```

output:

```
   A,B
0  a,1
1  b,2
2  c,3
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway, I want 2 columns A and B.
Is there anyway to delete the index ?
     blank = [''] * len(arr1)
     df.index = blank
this is not working.

Comment: No you can't, except for display/export: `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: I want the return type as Dataframe

Comment: Then it's not possible